# How to Import or Export Rules into KIE workbench?

Tags: drools, rules, kie, drools-flow

Is it possible to import or export the rules into KIE workbench? I am working on Drools using KIE workbench.

Answer (score 0):

In my [answer of this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810758/how-to-manipulate-guided-decision-table-from-java-api-in-drools/34824972#34824972) I explain how the Kie-Workbench uses Git as a repository for all its assets (rules, decision tables, processes, etc.). This answer also shows how you can get a clone of that repository, do some changes on it and push those changes back to the Kie-Workbench.

If you are planning to upload rules in .drl format, this may be the easiest way to do it.

Hope it helps,