# How can I connect Kie Workbench with eclipse, So that I can use the project created in kie workbench in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, drools, drools-guvnor, kie, kie-wb

I want to make a rest call and am not getting any option for making a rest call on kie workbench. So is it possible that I can make a project in kie workbench and then connect this project with eclipse to do coding.

Answer (score 1):

In this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810758/how-to-manipulate-guided-decision-table-from-java-api-in-drools/34824972#34824972) I explain how the kie-workbench internally uses git and maven to store its projects. The post also explains how a project from the kie-workbench can be cloned using git into a local working copy. Once cloned, you will see that the project is actually a maven project. You can then do whatever modification you need to (and even compile it, run tests on it, etc.) and then push the changes back to the kie-workbench.

I'm not familiar with Eclipse, but it may even a way to automate the cloning + opening of the project + pushing of the changes.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Can we setup standalone drools workbench source code(6.3.)  for edit (not kie workbench) with any ide (like eclipse) and to create war file(with drools workbench only)

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the concept of Kie Server ? It can be deployed in the same container as the workbench and any project you build in workbench can be built and deployed on the kie server. You can make rest calls to this server.
Eclipse does allow git cloning and commits.