# Transferring projects and repositories from one Drools workbench instance to another

Tags: drools, kie, kie-workbench

I have instances of the Drools workbench on two different machines. I am interested in transferring projects, repositories and workflows from one machine to the other. How is this accomplished? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily achieved by cloning - using git - the repositories from the kie-wb instances, moving whatever file/project you want and pushing the changes to the target kie-wb.

You can use [the answer in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810758/how-to-manipulate-guided-decision-table-from-java-api-in-drools/34824972#comment61862183_34824972) as a guide on how to clone a git repository from a kie-wb instance.

Of course, [Drools' documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#wb.VFSRepository) itself is a valuable place to get started too.

Hope it helps,

Comment: How can I do this directly. I mean suppose I click on the "Build and Deploy" button in kie-wb and I want the target .jar file to reside on a remote server as soon as it is built and not on the local filesystem.

Comment: @EdmDroid did you find a way to deploy the jar to a remote server ?

Comment: @monsoonrainbow no